# Getting an error code 80 on textlocal

Tags: java

I am using TextLocal tool to send SMS in my java code. I am using the same code snippet given [here](http://api.textlocal.in/docs/sendsms).

This is a transactional account. I am getting the following error

```
{"errors":[{"code":80,"message":"Invalid template"}],"status":"failure"}
```

This error code is nowhere found in the TextLocal documentation. Please let me know the solution if anyone has faced this issue before.

Answer (score 4):

This was happening because the TextLocal transactional messages should be given a message template through the TextLocal dashboard and all the SMS sent should follow all the rules of these messages.
After the template has been created and followed, the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 3):

go to Your login dashboard of textlocal
Then in send  menu go to template and draft.

then open your template to see the message format.
And provide same massage format to your java method to send message.

Hope may it help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
Few quick points to check 

1.Is the message that you are passing in your API as per your approved
    templates? If not, this error will come in response to your API. You
    can check your approved templates under Send -> Templates & Drafts 
     
2.Are all special characters in your template (&, @, #...) URL
    encoded? 
3.Are you using the same placeholder name
    for multiple dynamic/replaceable parameters in your API? They have
    to be unique.  
4.Are you exceeding the max character length set for
    the placeholder?  Are you using a newline character? Replace all the
    newline characters with %n
```

The above points are from textlocal SMS API documentation. You can also try copying the content of approved textlocal template into the Java code.

Comment: Hi I have done the same as you mentioned in the list above. This is my url: https://api.textlocal.in/send/?apikey=bUkJCEddasdasd4tqEusOHTLDjwnM47GVF9aVUTlKa&numbers=1234567890&message=2950%20is%20the%20otp%20for%20app%20registration.%20Thanks%20-%20IC%20INN%20PVT%20LTD&sender=TCLCLC. I get error 80 for this

Comment: have you checked the correctness of api key and sender id?

Comment: Yes. Everything was fine but I was getting the error because I had a space after sender ID like instead of TCLXLX it should have been TCLXLX%20. I spoke with the customer care and they cleared it up. This might be just in my case and not a regular occurance

Answer (score 0):

This because of the sending message content doesn't match the template which you created on the textlocal account.

1. check template is created or not. If not create a template and try.
2. If created check current message content match with your existing template.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because,

> From a transactional account you can send only those messages that
> match one of your pre-approved templates. Please ensure that your
> messages match one of the approved template formats.

To create a Template,
**Go to Your login dashboard of textlocal-> Send -> Templates and Drafts**.
Then create a Template. Templates can be 2 types *Static & Dynamic*. You can create both by using this. Template message format should match the format in your code.

I am providing a link.. This will help to understand this more clearly.

[How to create and format template](https://www.textlocal.in/how-to-create-and-edit-templates/)